# Passing variable through pages in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, variables

I have a WordPress project on in which I need to pass a variable from one page to another.

**PAGE ONE:** This page contains **LINK ONE**, **LINK TWO** & **LINK THREE**

**PAGE TWO**: This page contains **TAB ONE**, **TAB TWO** & **TAB THREE**

When you click on **LINK TWO** in **PAGE ONE**, it goes to **PAGE TWO** and needs to activate **TAB TWO** in jQuery.

The jQuery part of it is fine, but I cannot work out how to pass a variable through the pages to activate the tab.

I tried passing a variable through the URL, but this requires I turn permalinks off, and the client needs this.

I also thought of setting up a separate page for each tab, and then setting up a variable for the last page visited, so **LINK TWO** would go to a new WordPress page called Tab Two, which would redirect to **PAGE TWO**, and I would have a variable knowing which button had been clicked. However this didn't work either because it redirected the page before setting the variable in PHP or jQuery.

So as of the moment I am a little bit stuck. Does anyone have any ideas of how this could be done? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: if you can't use client-side methods to pass the data, then use server-side: sessions, cookies, yada yada yada

Comment: `I tried passing a variable through the URL, but this requires I turn permalinks off, and the client needs this.` => Why that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little tricky but let's try say you have the the link URL on **tab two** is `href='/page-2'` in page one, now pass the hash value in this link like `href='/page-2/#tab2'`

now lets move on the page two, detect the hash value with the help of javascript on page two like:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // hash value exists
  // Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 

 // Determine the success or failure
 var patt=/tab2/g;
 var result=patt.test(hash);

 if( result ){
    // Success Message
    alert(hash);
   // now here activate or open your tab
 }

}
```